# iPhoto like image preview using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, preview

Is there a jQuery plugin that allows to preview images the way as in Apple iPhoto? (hovering with the mouse over the image and when moving showing different images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this one: https://gist.github.com/188986